# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en relación a obtener registros basados en una tabla generada de muchos a muchos?

Tags: sql, .net, linq

La idea que requiero satisfacer es extraer los registros de una tabla que esta relacionada a una tabla generada de una relación muchos a muchos, es decir que son tres tablas, por ejemplo están Clientes, VendedorClientes y Vendedores, pero de las tres tablas solo necesito datos de la tabla Cliente pero en relación a que no salgan los clientes que ya tienen un vendedor asignado.

Intente hacer esta consulta:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Clientes c LEFT JOIN VendedorClientes vc ON c.ClienteID != vc.ClienteID WHERE vc.VendedorID = 1;
```

Esta consulta funciona cuando hay por lo menos un registro en VendedorClientes donde se valide el ID del vendedor indicado en el WHERE pero no funciona cuando no hay registros que no tengan el ID de vendedor o que simplemente no hayan registros con esa diferencia.

Imagino que es comprensible que la tabla que contiene las claves foráneas de Clientes como de Vendedores es la tabla VendedorClientes pero que solo se utiliza las tablas Cliente y VendedorClientes únicamente, así que espero que me puedan colaborar con esto.

PD: Si no es mucho pedir, me gustaría que también me ayudaran a resolver esto pero utilizando LINQ, ahora estoy trabajando en un proyecto ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los clientes que no existen en una tabla, simplemente podemos usar la opción `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Clientes c 
WHERE  c.ClienteID NOT IN( SELECT vc.ClienteID FROM VendedorClientes vc);
```

Comment: Oye @LuisCazares resulta que la consulta que usted hizo me ayudo bastante, solo modifique el SELECT interior del IN colocándole un WHERE buscando el vendedor que necesitaba para excluir a los que ya estaban asociado a este... se lo agradezco bastante